# Convert traditional HiFi to wireless?

Tags: speakers, cable, wireless

I have a great Wharfedale Vardus 5-piece set and I'd like to understand if/what options I have to replace the cable connections with a wireless solution (I understand there are bluetooth and WiFi arrangements, but I only see ready-made sets).

Comment: What source are you speakers currently wired to, a hi-fi amp?

Comment: Used to be wired to a Yamaha amp. but the guy is no longer with us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you will need to provide a power amplifier for each different speaker cabinet. You did not mention what model you have so we don't know what power, what kind of processing, etc. you would need.

Then you will need to divide your signal (source not disclosed) into the channels appropriate for each speaker cabinet and come up with five wireless links that would operate together without interference.

This is quite a considerable engineering exercise. It may be the case where if you have to come here and ask, you may not be up to the challenge.  Frankly, ordinary wires are FAR SUPERIOR to any kind of wireless link.

Comment: Then you'd need to figure out how to get them all in phase :/ +1 for "use wires."

Comment: Another +1 for wires. Wireless is an almost acceptable alternative when you just can't use wires for some reason

Comment: In the pro audio and film/video production world, we have the axiom: "A $30 cable is far superior to a $3000 wireless kit."

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and the above replies! I don't have a hard reason not to use wires other than the aesthetic aspect of things. Following your answers I'm dropping the wireless idea and will stick with wires. Thanks a bunch!